# Password Problems

Tags: password

Whenever I try to change settings for the Admin account or download any files/programs it asks for a password. I do not know/remember this password. I've tried resetting it and making a new account using ROOT, but it wont let me. when I try to change my password, this comes up. "Authentication token manipulation error". I would greatly appreciate some help in this matter.

Comment: correction. whenever i try to INSTALL any files/programs.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your question need to be completed (we can't know which version of Ubuntu you are speaking of, which commands/programs you are using, etc. Also, do not add a comment to correct things, edit your question. Have you read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo?

Answer (score 0):

http://geekyshow.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-hackreset-kali-linux-login.html

I suggest these steps for resetting the root password from the grub boot loader. It works great for Kali Linux and should also work for other Linux distros.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.